# can't able to delete image if already exists in c#

Tags: c#

I have been created upload image with edit and update.

When i insert image it will be stored both in hard drive and database.

If edit and upload another and click update, it will changed in gridview. but also i want to delete if already uploaded image in hard drive.

Here is my full source:

```
protected void btnsub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();
            if (Textid.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
            {
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedure3", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Textid.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Textusername.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class", Textclass.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", Textsection.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Textaddress.Text.Trim());
                try
                {
                    string filename = Image1.ImageUrl.Substring(Image1.ImageUrl.IndexOf('/')+1);
                    string filepath = @"E\student\student\student\Images";
                    if (Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(filepath)))
                    {
                        File.Delete(filepath);
                    }
                    if (fileupload.PostedFile.FileName.Length > 0)
                    {                        
                        filename = Path.GetFileName(fileupload.PostedFile.FileName);

                        fileupload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + filename));
                    } 

                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image",(filename.Length>0)? "Images/" + filename:string.Empty);
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();                    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    btnsub.Text = ex.Message;
                }
                Response.Redirect("studententry.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedure1", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Textusername.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class", Textclass.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", Textsection.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Textaddress.Text.Trim());
                try
                {
                    string filename = string.Empty;
                    if (fileupload.PostedFile.FileName.Length > 0)
                    {
                        filename = Path.GetFileName(fileupload.PostedFile.FileName);
                        fileupload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + filename));
                    }
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image",(filename.Length>0)? "Images/" + filename:string.Empty);
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();                    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    btnsub.Text = ex.Message;
                }
                Response.Redirect("studententry.aspx");
            }
        }
```

May i know, how to delete if already uploaded image in the hard drive?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: what is the exception ?

Comment: if (Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(filepath)))
                    {
                        File.Delete(filepath);
                    } what does it mean if directory exists then you delete it and again you try to saveas image on same directory

Comment: Patel is right, and you missed : sign, E:\student\...

Comment: sorry.. i think that part of code will be incorrect.. can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment this code, is useless as well as wrong, SaveAs will overwright the file

```
              string filepath = @"E\student\student\student\Images";
                if (Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(filepath)))
                {
                    File.Delete(filepath);
                }
```

if you really really want to delete:

```
if (fileupload.PostedFile.FileName.Length > 0)
{                        
filename = Path.GetFileName(fileupload.PostedFile.FileName);
if(File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + filename)))
     File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + filename));
fileupload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + filename));
}
```

edit again:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Images"));
foreach(string f in files) File.Delete (f);

if (fileupload.PostedFile.FileName.Length > 0)
{                        
filename = Path.GetFileName(fileupload.PostedFile.FileName);
fileupload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + filename));
}
```

Comment: You want to delete to save again, there is no need to delete, just saveas

Comment: not like that, when edit mode, if i change image and update, i want to delete already uploaded image..

Comment: ah, you want to cancel every image in directory?

Comment: how do i say.. far example step 1: insert image(ex:tree.jpg) 2.edit image and insert another one image(ex:garden.jpg) and submit. so in the hard drive now only contain garden.jpg and don't include tree.jpg..

Comment: sorry.. its working fine.. and also if upload same image, then it shows already exist in alert.. for that what is the code for validation.. can you help me? thanks

Comment: hi..can you help what should i do, if upload same image, it shows alert?

Comment: you want to show an alert when the user upload the same filename?

Comment: yeah. for example if i upload tree.jpg. once.. and i will upload again that same image tree.jpg, and click submit, it shows in alert, the image already exist, please upload new one.. thank you..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95439/discussion-between-user5507337-and-rani).